# Where can I find the solutions to "The Algorithm Design Manual"?

Tags: algorithm

The book is full of interesting questions, but since I am learning it myself, it would be a great help if I can find solutions to at least some of the questions.

Anyone knows anything about this?

Comment: Link is working now: http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/The_Algorithms_Design_Manual_%28Second_Edition%29

Comment: The solutions are up once again! http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The book's website, [algorist.com](https://www.algorist.com/) has a [wiki](https://www.algorist.com/algowiki/index.php) with solutions.

Comment: this links does not work, just FYI.

Comment: It did in February :) They must have taken it off the mediawiki. Sorry! The book's webpage still appears to point to sunysb's mediawiki, so they haven't got the memo yet!

Comment: Hope this Cache links helps http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/Introduction-TADM2E

Comment: blog link http://blog.panictank.net/category/algorithmndesignmanualsolutions/

Comment: it seems the wiki was moved to:
http://nbl.cewit.stonybrook.edu:60128/mediawiki/index.php/Introduction-TADM2E

Comment: None of the above links are working. There are, however, some PDF's of the solutions available. An updated link is still more helpful and accessible.

Comment: updated link:
http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php/Data-structures-TADM2E-2

Comment: The Algorist wiki doesn't seem to have solutions for all the questions - is this a work-in-progress, or are some questions intentionally left unanswered?

Comment: @Shuklaswag As the wiki says "The Wiki is an experiment, a grass-roots effort to create an answer key to aid self-study with Steven Skiena's The Algorithm Design Manual. Students and other readers are encouraged to contribute hints and answers to all odd numbered problems in the book, or expand/improve the solution contributed by others." So yes in a sense it is a work in progress. But there is unlikely to be another source of the answers, as *this* is sanctioned by the author/publisher, and other sources (like ones with more answers) would not have such a status.