# Steven Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual Solutions

Tags: algorithm, solution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the solutions to “The Algorithm Design Manual”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112057/where-can-i-find-the-solutions-to-the-algorithm-design-manual)

I'm currently reading "The Algorithm Design Manual" by Steven Skiena.
Great book so far, but I'm wondering if there are solutions available to the exercises in the book? The link on www.algorist.com that directs you to the "Solutions Wiki" is not working.

Does anyone know of an archived version that's available to download or even another website where I can find them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the solutions to "The Algorithm Design Manual"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112057/where-can-i-find-the-solutions-to-the-algorithm-design-manual) or http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2217/solutions-to-algorithm-design-manual  Try again later - the site appears to be a bit of a yoyo

Comment: Yeah, the duplicate on stackoverflow was asked a year and a half ago. Thanks for the response, looks like I'll have to wait it out.

Comment: Top book. Email Skiena and ask politely.